# How to create a Freeform multipage form inside of two separate form tags?

Tags: forms, solspace-freeform

I'm trying to create a form which passes field values over multiple pages. The first part is in the footer of the website, which, when filled out, should take you to an expanded version of the same form (with added fields), filling out whichever fields were submitted through the first form.

The problem is that I need to do this in two separate form tags (one which exists in my footer template, another for my form page), but all of the examples I've seen have all form "pages" in one tag pair.

E.g. http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/form#multipage_surveys

Anyone know if it's possible to do the above, but not within the same form tag?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the Solspace example is submitting the form to itself, and revealing different chunks with each submit. If you wanted to start the form in the footer, you'd have to have the first chunk there, and then each subsequent chunk would be revealed in the same spot.

I'm not sure how to tackle your goal with something concise that will only send the email when the form is completed.

You could use Safecracker. The first form page would have enough to get the entry started, and you could use hidden input fields to reference the entry on each subsequent page. You'd be creating an entry with a bunch of fields left incomplete, and then editing the entry on each subsequent page, revealing different chunks of fields to fill in.

You could then [use a post-processor template or Postmaster](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/5912/293) to send notifications when the entry is complete. The post-processor template might give you more control over that, as Postmaster relies on triggers, such as a new channel entry.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with an embed using the [paging_url](http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/form#paging_url) and [multipage_page](http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/form#multipage_page) parameters and force multipage to always be on page one in the footer, but also force submit to go to the segments of your choosing for page 2 after filling it out in the footer. Notifications do not send until a multipage form is complete.